# res.render('index.html', {layout : null}) generating error

Tags: node.js

following demo project [Here](http://angular-client-side-auth.herokuapp.com/login) and blog post [Here](http://www.frederiknakstad.com/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/).

He is using `jade engine` which I `don't want` to use instead using Angularjs templating and routing.

**Root folder is**

```
client > js (contain all js files)
       > views > partials > html files
       > index.html
```

After changes in his code I am stuck with the below code

I am unable to send proper response.

if I use `res.render('index.html', {layout : null});` than get error when refresh page

**ERROR :**

```
Error: Cannot find module 'html'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
```

if I use `res.redirect('/')` than refresh the page always send me root (/) defined in app.js.

**Needed :** I want to send response or not to be on the same page even if I refresh the browser.

```
{
        path: '/*',
        httpMethod: 'GET',
        middleware: [function(req, res) {
           var role = userRoles.public, username = '';
        if(req.user) {
            role = req.user.role;
            username = req.user.username;
        }
        res.cookie('user', JSON.stringify({
            'username': username,
            'role': role
        }));
            //res.render('index.html', {layout : null});
            //res.redirect('/');

        }],
        accessLevel: accessLevels.public
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not using a backend template language (like jade), then you want to use [res.sendfile](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.sendfile) instead of [res.render](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render). Render will look for a template engine matching the extension of the file (such as .jade) and then run the file through it. In this case, it assumes there must be a rendering engine called html, but there is not. SendFile will simply transfer the file as-is with the appropriate headers.

EDIT:

I'm still not 100% sure what you're asking, but I think what you're saying is you want your wildcard route to redirect people to the homepage if they aren't logged in, but if they are, then let other routes take over.

If that is the case you just need to put in a check in your "middleware" function for the `/*` route.

Instead of:

```
function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

Use some type of conditional logic:

```
function (req, res, next) {
    if (/* !req.cookie.something or whatever */)
        res.redirect('/');
    else
        next(); // continue on to the next applicable (matching) route handler
}
```

That way you won't always get caught in the redirect loop. Obviously, the above conditional logic could be asynchronous if necessary.

I still believe `res.sendfile` is the correct answer to the other portion of your question, just as the github members also suggested.

Comment: Or use the `express.static` middleware instead of `res.sendfile`.

Comment: @bret-copeland, res.redirect(req.url); creates loop. I don't want to use res.sendfile. Already using express.static.

Comment: @Rashid Sorry, I misread. I thought you asked how to send a redirect that would essentially refresh the page (which is useful sometimes). If you're already using express.static to serve html pages, then I'm not sure why you were using res.render, or what your question is exactly? Perhaps help me understand what "I want to send response or not to be on the same page even if I refresh the browser" means. Also, just to point out, res.sendfile and express.static are not equivalent. There are many situations where direct calls to sendfile are still appropriate or necessary.

Comment: @bret-copeland, Thanks for the reply. Here is the application on Github which I am studing is using Jade engine. I want to use html instead. Here is the issue discussed https://github.com/fnakstad/angular-client-side-auth/issues/13 . See if you have any solution to that.